# Rails Slider with image caption

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I tried to follow this tutorial to integrate an image gallery in my Rails 4 app.

https://www.toptal.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-helper-bootstrap-carousel

I previously had one which had the attributes I wanted to display in the way I wanted, but I couldn't get the controls to work.

Using this tutorial, I can have controls, but I can't figure out how to integrate the caption text that I want to display with the image.

I have models called Project and Gallery. The associations are:

Project.rb

```
has_many :galleries
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :galleries,  reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
```

Gallery.rb

```
belongs_to :project
```

The attributes in my gallery table are:

```
image             :string
image_alt         :string
image_description :text
image_credit      :string
project_id        :integer
```

Following the tutorial, I added the carousel helper:

```
module CarouselHelper
  def carousel_for(images)
    Carousel.new(self, images).html
  end

  class Carousel
    def initialize(view, images)
      @view, @images = view, images
      @uid = SecureRandom.hex(6)
    end

    def html
      content = safe_join([indicators, slides, controls])
      content_tag(:div, content, id: uid, class: 'carousel slide')
    end

    private

    attr_accessor :view, :images, :uid
    delegate :link_to, :content_tag, :image_tag, :safe_join, to: :view

    def indicators
      items = images.count.times.map { |index| indicator_tag(index) }
      content_tag(:ol, safe_join(items), class: 'carousel-indicators')
    end

    def indicator_tag(index)
      options = {
        class: (index.zero? ? 'active' : ''),
        data: { 
          target: uid, 
          slide_to: index
        }
      }

      content_tag(:li, '', options)
    end

    def slides
      items = images.map.with_index { |image, index| slide_tag(image, index.zero?) }
      content_tag(:div, safe_join(items), class: 'carousel-inner')
    end

    def slide_tag(image, is_active)
      options = {
        class: (is_active ? 'item active' : 'item'),
      }

      content_tag(:div, image_tag(image), options)
    end

    def controls
      safe_join([control_tag('left'), control_tag('right')])
    end

    def control_tag(direction)
      options = {
        class: "#{direction} carousel-control",
        data: { slide: direction == 'left' ? 'prev' : 'next' }
      }

      icon = content_tag(:i, '', class: "glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-#{direction}")
      control = link_to(icon, "##{uid}", options)
    end
  end
end
```

In my project controller I have:

```
def show

    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    @image_urls=[]
      @project.galleries.each do |gallery|
        @image_urls.push(gallery.image.url) 
      end

  end
```

I don't know what the reference to "push" in that method means. Someone helped me in this post:

[Rails 4 - carousel helper - image gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37107625/rails-4-carousel-helper-image-gallery)

- they use paperclip - which I do not use (I have carrierwave) but this line does not cause an error.

Then in my projects show, I have:

```
   <%= carousel_for(@image_urls) %>
```

I can't figure out how to add the caption, image alt and image credit to the image.

If I add it to the bracketed text inside the carousel_for, I get an error saying that there is only one attribute expected. Even still, if this worked, how would I format those elements?

Can anyone help?

Comment: check `gallery.image.url` output on the rails console.

Comment: I can display the images, but now Im trying to figure out how to display the caption attributes along side  the image

Comment: did you checked with `gallery.image.path`

Comment: Gallery.first.image.url
  Gallery Load (2.7ms)  SELECT  "galleries".* FROM "galleries"  ORDER BY "galleries"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
 => "https://carrierwaveimageuploads.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/gallery/image/1/search.png" 
2.3.0p0 :003 >

Comment: Gallery.first.image.path
  Gallery Load (2.5ms)  SELECT  "galleries".* FROM "galleries"  ORDER BY "galleries"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
 => "uploads/gallery/image/1/search.png"

Comment: I have the images loading. What I'm trying to achieve is to add captions

Comment: @user2860931 hey again, I have an alternative for your slider. which contains captions and all. Its a bootstrap slider.

Comment: Hi @PraveshKhatri I tried the standard bootstrap - i couldn't get the controls to work. Im now trying to figure out whether the toptal tutorial might work out. Its confusing because so many lines of that helper aren't explained. For now, I'm trying to figure out how to get captions into that version.

Comment: I have already done it for you. In standard Bootstrap

Comment: Hi @PraveshKhatri - where did you do it?

Comment: actually i have use it in my rails application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

in your controller

```
def show
    @project = Project.find(params[:id]) //this will give you only one object
    @allimages = Project.galleries.all   // this will give you many objects
end
```

In your view replace by

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" style="height:520px; margin-bottom: 100px; background: #d1dbde;">

 <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
   <% @allimages.each do |gallery| %>
      <% if gallery == @allimages.first%>
        <div class="item active">
         <%= image_tag(gallery.image.url, :class => "carousel_image") %> 
          <div class="carousel-caption image_caption">
            <h3><strong><%= link_to(gallery.title , image_path(gallery.id))%></strong></h3>  
            <h4><%= truncate(gallery.body, length: 75) %></h4>          
          </div>
        </div>
      <% else %>
       <div class="item">
         <%= image_tag(gallery.image.url, :class => "carousel_image") %>
          <div class="carousel-caption image_caption">
            <h3><strong><%= link_to(gallery.title , image_path(gallery.id))%></strong></h3>  
            <h4><%= truncate(gallery.body, length: 75) %></h4>          
          </div>
        </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

In your custom css file

```
.carousel_image{
    height: 450px !important;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}
.image_caption{
    top: 72%;
}
```

Comment: I can't see how this incorporates my caption elements (image_description / image_alt / image credit)

Comment: I've managed to figure out how to adapt this for my purpose. I've dumped the helper method in the toptal tutorial. thanks again